# Как оптимально настроить буферы для проксирования в nginx?

Tags: nginx

Есть сервер на NodeJS + Express, запросы к которому проксируются через Nginx. Начал замечать в логах, что один из GET-запросов вызывает предупреждение:

> an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file

Посмотрел статистику. Сервер возвращает в ответ на запрос json размером от 100кб до 10мб (в зависимости от состояния приложения). По сети в сжатом состоянии (gzip) передаётся несколько сотен килобайт данных.

Как оптимально настроить буферы для данных такого размера? Нужно ли вообще устанавливать какое-то нестандартное значения размера буфера?

Comment: Ну можно понастраивать proxy_buffers. Впрочем стоит сначала выяснить, а есть ли какое-то ухудшение. Скорее всего этот временный файл всё равно не доезжает до реального диска, а благополучно оседает и умирает вфайловом кеше ос, так что никой практической разницы не будет

Comment: @AlexeyTen зачем тогда nginx вообще создаёт временный файл?

Comment: Ну он же не знает сколько там будет, 10Мб или 10Гб. Порог превышен, создаёт файл